# Does the nuclear reactor remain radioactive after fuel assemble have been removed?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

Uranium pellets are packed as fuel rods, using Zirconium Alloy Cladding. In a steady operational state rector core will be full of radiation. But suppose that all fuel rods are withdrawn will the reactor core no longer remain radioactive and safe for Humans to visit and provide maintenance. Can same be said about other components ex. control rods and graphite block, will they be safe or contaminated. I am assuming no corrosion of Zirconium Alloy had occurred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's take the example of PWR reactors:
Everything that has remained in the neutron flux for a long time is radioactive, including the control rods, the internal structures of the vessel, and the vessel itself at various levels: the vessel is more radioactive in its central part than on the bottom or the cover, this being due to the distribution of the neutron flux.
The entire primary circuit is contaminated to varying degrees by the inevitable corrosion products transported by the primary water stream, because these products are activated each time it passes through the core.
The exchangers are highly contaminated due to their large exchange surface.
The fuel may also present micro-breaks in the zircaloy sheath which will allow some fission products to pass.
The new EPR reactor at Taishan 1 (China) has just been shut down for a year due to micro-cladding ruptures.
Increasing the lifetime of reactors complicates maintenance in terms of radiation protection.

Comment: Nice answer but it doesn't explain why: *'Everything that has remained in the neutron flux for a long time is radioactive, including the control rods, [...]'*

Comment: How do we then perform maintenance on reactor?

Comment: Practically all materials placed in fluxes of neutrons, and especially thermal neutrons, become radioactive especially by neutron capture .  See for example wikipedia 
 "Neutron_activation " .

Comment: I don't know how to answer the maintenance question in 10 lines. Each part of the primary circuit is monitored according to appropriate and different procedures. All known non-destructive testing means will be used on a reactor primary circuit. The pressure vessel is particularly inspected at regular intervals during shutdown periods. Procedures are increasingly automated to avoid personnel working under radiation as much as possible.

Comment: The answer is correct, but doesn't make the distinction between the radioactivity in the fuel and the activity in the activated materials.  The radioactivity in the fuel is much, much higher.  If you get close to the spent fuel (with no shielding), it will kill you quickly.  While the materials left behind are radioactive, you can go into the vessel and do maintenance.

Comment: So with proper precautions taken we can go and work inside the reactors?

Comment: The question initially states that  :  " But suppose that all fuel rods are withdrawn "  .

Comment: In French PWRs, you cannot descend into the empty pressure vessel.
At a minimum , it will be divers who will do underwater examinations .
But there is a very complex, very expensive machine that allows all non-destructive testing of the vessel without human intervention: it is moved from reactor to reactor according to maintenance periods.